# Is it possible to display some content over a navigationpage in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

So I was thinking of displaying a small statusbar during the debugging over my navigation page. Basically something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<NavigationPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="Drivr.Pages.MainPage">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Label Text="Status of app" Grid.Row="0" />
        <NavigationPage x:Name="MainNavigation" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Row="0"></NavigationPage>
    </Grid>
</NavigationPage>
```

Not exactly that of course, but you have the idea. So when there is like an error or I want to try something I could just display it there instead of outputting it to the console. Is it possible of doing something similar to this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but not like this.

The NavigationPage is a construct that allows you to maintain a navigation stack - that is a set of pages where the top page is the currently visible one and clicking "Back" button removes (pops) the top page so the previous one becomes the top one.

You could also pop all the way to the root of the navigation stack so you can go "home". With several NavigationPages where a one is put (pushed) you could create a set of checkpoints so the user can quickly go back to a previous page that may be further than one step back.

In your case you could add to App.cs' constructor:

```
MainPage = new NavigationPage(new ContentPage{ 
  Content = new Label { Text = "here we are" }
});
```

This sets up a root NavigationPage, so in your other pages you can do:

```
async void OnButtonClick(...){
  await Navigation.PushAsync(new MyNextPage());
}
```

Normally the "Back" button will show up by itself, and now you'd have a simple 2-page app.